# Serialization in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In Django Rest Framework. I have a program that lets a user post some data. I serialize this input, but with this input I also save it to another model and create some default values for it and return them to the user. But I am getting slightly confused on whether or not I should serialize that model too.

```
class FileExample(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = FileExampleSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            other_model = OtherModel(name=request.FILES['file'].name, type_obj='file')
            other_model.save()
            return Response({'url': other_model.url}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

For example `OtherModel` is my other model object that I create which creates some default values. But I was looking at nested serializers but this did not achieve what I wanted, as it threw an error that it was missing a required value. My question is my code will work like this, but should I be serializing `OtherModel` as well?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to serialize the data for `OtherModel`, if you create the instance of it with the right data it should work anyways, but it's always a good practise to serialize everything so as to have it pass the necessary validations and normalizations.

Comment: @Shinratensei That makes, sense, but I am still getting confused as to where I would use that serialization, would it be in my `create` method in my `FileExampleSerializer` or would it be in my view?

Comment: Think I figured it out, I need the `to_representation` method.

Comment: To serialize the instance in order to save it, you need the `create` method, and possibly the `update` method too, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You use the serializer for creating, updating and displaying your data.

For instance, if you use `FileExampleSerializer(data=request.data)`

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = FileExampleSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
       serializer.save()
       data = serializer.data
    else:
       data = serialiyer.errors
    
    return Response(data=data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

you create a new entry at your database. `save()` invokes the `create()` method in your serializer.

For instance, if you use `FileExampleSerializer(data=request.data, instance=OtherModel.object.get(id=1)))`

```
def put(self, request, format=None):
    instance=OtherModel.object.get(id=1)
    serializer = FileExampleSerializer(data=request.data, instance=instance)
    if serializer.is_valid():
       serializer.save()
       data = serializer.data
    else:
       data = serialiyer.errors
    
    return Response(data=data, status=204)
```

your serializer detects that your want to update values of `instance`. `save()` invokes `update()` in your serialiyer and returns the updated instance.

`is_valid()` checks if incoming data has the correct format and all keys are present.

If your want to change behaviour of displaying your data your can override `to_representation()`. For instance, your nested data should be displayed instead of

```
{
"foo": "bar",
"alice": [
        "john": 1,
        "bob": 2
         ] 
}
```

that way

```
{
"foo": "bar",
"john": 1,
"bob": 2
}
```